# How to getItem every time, value is changed/updated. localStorage, JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a shopping cart where i add and remove items, and i keep data in the `localStorage`.

I add my items like this:

```
const addItemToCart = (item: Object) => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;

    let myCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart') || '[]');
    myCart.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem('myCart', JSON.stringify(myCart));
  };
```

The shopping cart is different component and i need to call in that single component `getItem()` every time i add item to cart.

Is there a way to watch attribute in localStorage? Because only way i see is to create some context.

Comment: You can maintain a state to track the cart in a common parent. The ease of doing so depends on how your app is structured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom event with listeners to effect on state change.

After adding/removing items (setItem), you can fire custom event:

```js
...
// As you update localStorage, update the state as well
localStorage.setItem('myCart', JSON.stringify(myCart));

// fired custom event on localStorage data changed
const event = new CustomEvent('localdatachanged');
document.dispatchEvent(event);

// Update the state with the array
...
```

and add event listener in place you want:

```js
document.addEventListener('localdatachanged', () => {
  // handler
});
```

In this case you can fire custom event in different places, but handle changes only in one place.

Comment: Thanks, sadly i already solved my problem with the context state. But thank you for your help

Comment: You a welcome. Anyway, this approach can be used in case of vanilla js

Answer (score 1):

localStorage does not have any state, so you have to create your own variable with state so that each time you update the localStorage, you also update the state variable:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
const addItemToCart = (item: Object) => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;

    let myCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart') || '[]');
    myCart.push(item);
    // As you update localStorage, update the state as well
    localStorage.setItem('myCart', JSON.stringify(myCart));
    // Update the state with the array
    setCart(myCart)
};
```